# Считать все личные сообщения в discord?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

Хочу реализовать поиск по всем личным сообщениям в `Discord` (по умолчанию в `Discord` этой функции нет)

Можно создать бота, добавить его на сервер, и с помощью бота все считывать, но тогда поиск будет работать только на этом сервере. То есть нужен бот или приложение или еще что-то, что будет иметь доступ к моим лс и что сможет считывать их.

Как такое реализовать? Каким путем действовать?

К данному моменту уже есть приложение с `APPLICATION ID` и `PUBLIC KEY`.